# Unsuccesssful table creation using SpringData and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Was creating three entities as below -

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name="user_id")
      private long id;

      @NotNull
      private String email;

      @NotNull
      private String name;

      @NotNull
      private String contact;

  //getters and setters 

}
```

Books.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="books")
    public class Books {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="isbn")
        private long isbn;

        @NotNull
        private String bookName;

        @NotNull
        private String bookDescription;

        @NotNull
        private String price;

        //getters and setters 
    }
```

Purchases.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="purchases")
public class Purchases {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String order_id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creation_time;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="isbn")
    private Books book;

     // getters and setters   
  }
```

And controller

```
@Controller
public class PurchaseController {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    BooksDAO booksDAO;

    @Autowired
    PurchasesDAO purchaseDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/createUser")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createUser(String email, String name, String contact){
        User user=null;
        try{
            user=new User(email,name,contact);
            userDAO.save(user);
            }catch(Exception e){
                return "Problem occured while saving user :"+e; 
            }   
          return "User succesfully created! (id = " + user.getId() + ")";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/createBook")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createBooks(String bookName, String bookDesc, String price){
        Books book=null;
        try{
            book=new Books(bookName,bookDesc,price);
            booksDAO.save(book);
            }catch(Exception e){
                return "Problem occured while saving book details :"+e; 
            }   
          return "Book succesfully created! (isbn = " + book.getIsbn() + " name = "+book.getBookName()+")";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/purchase")
    @ResponseBody
    public String purchase(Long user_id, Long isbn){
        Books book=null;
        User user=null;
        Purchases purchase=null;
        Date creation_date=new Date();
        try{
            book=booksDAO.findOne(isbn);
            user=userDAO.findOne(user_id);
            System.out.println("book= "+book+" and user= "+user+"");
            if(book.getIsbn()==0 || user.getId()==0){
                return "Book with isbn="+isbn+" or user with user id ="+user_id+" not found.";
            }
            purchase = new Purchases(creation_date,user,book);
            purchaseDAO.save(purchase);

        }catch(Exception e){
            return "Exception occured while purchasing book ["+e+"]";
        }

        return "Book purchased";
    }}
```

The dao interface extends `CrudRepository<Class, Long>{}` and is annotated as `transactional`. The problem is the third table that is purchase.java is not getting created. Getting the following on console.

```
2016-05-03 18:13:33.876  INFO 19570 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-05-03 18:13:33.920  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2016-05-03 18:13:33.921  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-05-03 18:13:33.922  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-05-03 18:13:34.062  INFO 19570 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-05-03 18:13:34.388  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-05-03 18:13:34.465  INFO 19570 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-05-03 18:13:34.707  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table purchases drop foreign key FK_laat6sjwiu2hcenno94vyj0jb
2016-05-03 18:13:34.716 ERROR 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table purchases drop foreign key FK_laat6sjwiu2hcenno94vyj0jb
2016-05-03 18:13:34.716 ERROR 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'purchase_books.purchases' doesn't exist
Hibernate: alter table purchases drop foreign key FK_klpjcob070n95mdvt1473hs1s
2016-05-03 18:13:34.716 ERROR 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table purchases drop foreign key FK_klpjcob070n95mdvt1473hs1s
2016-05-03 18:13:34.716 ERROR 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'purchase_books.purchases' doesn't exist
Hibernate: drop table if exists books
Hibernate: drop table if exists purchases
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_details
Hibernate: create table books (isbn bigint not null auto_increment, book_description varchar(255) not null, book_name varchar(255) not null, price varchar(255) not null, primary key (isbn))
Hibernate: create table purchases (order_id bigint not null auto_increment, creation_time datetime, isbn bigint, user_id bigint, primary key (order_id))
Hibernate: create table user_details (user_id bigint not null auto_increment, contact varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (user_id))
Hibernate: alter table purchases add constraint FK_laat6sjwiu2hcenno94vyj0jb foreign key (isbn) references books (isbn)
Hibernate: alter table purchases add constraint FK_klpjcob070n95mdvt1473hs1s foreign key (user_id) references user_details (user_id)
2016-05-03 18:13:37.037  INFO 19570 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Using SpringBoot for running the application. In the message is the problem mentioned but not able to figure out. Can anybody please elaborate this or tell how to resolve the same ? Table are created using hibernate in the sql database.

Comment: You seem to be missing some code. The purchases object is not here and that's what most of the errors relate to.

Comment: There is no issue with the creation of the tables, why would you think so. The errors don't indicate that the tables cannot be created, those are created successfully (see the `create table` statements in the logging). If that would have failed your application wouldn't have started.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There was a problem in defining primary key field in purchases entity which was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type on your Purchases order_id. I think you may want it to be a numeric, perhaps of type "long".

Comment: Have made changes as mentioned, but the same problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` for a `String` property

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String order_id;
```

Change it to the `Long`, for an example

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long order_id;
```

Please, don't use table names like `user`. It is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL.

Comment: ok, have changed as mentioned. But the same problem still persists.

Comment: @Harshit Is the stack trace same? Please, put a new stack trace and format it as a code (Ctrl + K).

Comment: there is some problem with creation of tables using hibernate. Can you find it from the stack trace ?

Comment: @Harshit `Unsuccessful: alter table purchases drop foreign key FK_laat6sjwiu2hcenno94vyj0jb` this? It will disappear :)